# How to identify ash deafening in the joist bay?

Tags: insulation, joists, asbestos, old-house

I have a Queens brick Townhouse built in 1906.  I was attempting to repair my basement ceiling joists and found several joist bays under my front door threshold/atrium with wooden boards encasing what looks like some loose rock fill.  My contractor thinks it's [ash deafening](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Ash_deafening) used over tile and mosaic above, and thinks it's fine to remove it so that we can have room to sister the joist.  He said that in the olden days, they used ash fill instead of plywood boards underneath tiles.

1. Is this ash deafening?
2. Is there a danger of this having asbestos?
3. Is it ok to remove without any structural issues?  i.e. can we remove it while we try to sister the joist without having what's above it cave in?  Will removing the fill cave in the mosaic tile above?

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are asbestos test kits you can buy to test for that.  If there is no asbestos you should be able to remove the stuff with no serious danger, though it would be wise to do it a little at a time in case some bozo did arrange it to be structural.

Comment: "Some bozo" was working more than a _hundred_ years ago with limited resources and primitive tools. Maybe don't judge so harshly unless you've trodden that path.

Comment: According to the Wiki link, there is _nothing_ structural about ash deafening, whatsoever, therefore, there's no problem with removing it. Whether that's ash deafening or not is a different question. TBH, it's hard to tell what we're looking at in this pic - maybe add a wider shot to give some perspective?

Comment: 1) yes. 2) yes. 3) yes. Wear a mask, double bag it, use tape, and label it asbestos... if you *really* care. You are free to do your own asbestos abatement provided this is single family residential property. And if this is the one time you deal with it in your life, you'll be fine. If you work on boilers from the 30s every day, then not so much.

Comment: @FreeMan I think the drawing is a pretty accurate representation of how it's encased in between joists and there is some rock like fill in it.    The boards are there to keep what's above it encased.  I cut a small square hole in it to see what's inside it's some rock like material.